# integral arising in statistical mechanics

Tags: calculus, integration, catalans-constant

The following integral arises in statistical mechanics of lattice models:

$
\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\ln\left(\, 1 +
\sqrt{\, 1 - a^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\phi\right)\,}\,\right)\,
\mathrm{d} \phi\quad$ with $\quad a \leq   1
$.

By trial and error, the integral was shown to be nearly equal to

$
\displaystyle I =
{\pi \over 4}\ln\left(2\right) + {\pi \over 4}
\ln\left(1 + \sqrt{\, 1 - Ga^{2}\, }\right)
$.

where $G$ denotes Catalan constant.

Is there a method of obtaining an exact analytical solution or justifying the approximate answer given above ?.

Comment: Please learn how to use Math Jax to typeset equations! [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a helpful guide

Comment: Wow, it’s remarkable if this trial-and-error is correct. How did you do it? Did you use RIES? http://mrob.com/pub/ries/index-2.html#source

Comment: Suspicious, as parameter $a$ is nowhere to be seen...

Comment: Where did the $a$ go?

Comment: For $a=1$, $I= 2G-\pi\ln\sqrt2$

Comment: Differentiating wrt $a$ gives an elliptic integral. Then the problem is reduced to integrating $K(a)/a$, which gives a generalized hypergeometric function:
$$I = \frac {\pi \ln 2} 2 - \frac {\pi a^2} {16}
 {_4 F_3} {\left( 1, 1, \frac 3 2, \frac 3 2; 2, 2, 2; a^2 \right)},
\quad |a| < 1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Maxim's comment
$$I(a) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\left(\, 1 +\sqrt{\, 1 - a^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\phi\right)\,}\,\right)\,d\phi$$
$$I'(a)=- \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{a \sin ^2(\phi)}{\sqrt{1-a^2 \sin ^2(\phi)} \left(1+\sqrt{1-a^2 \sin^2(\phi)}\right)}\,d\phi=\frac{\pi -2 K\left(a^2\right)}{2 a}$$

$$\int \frac{K\left(a^2\right)}{ a}\,da=-\frac{1}{4} G_{3,3}^{2,2}\left(-a^2|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1 \\
 0,0,0
\end{array}
\right)$$ and $I(0)=\frac{1}{2} \pi  \log (2)$.

After simplifications, this led me (laboriously) to @Maxim's result.

$$I(a) = \frac {\pi } 2 \log( 2)- \frac {\pi a^2} {16}  {_4 F_3} {\left( 1, 1, \frac 3 2, \frac 3 2; 2, 2, 2; a^2 \right)}$$
The good approximation given in the post
$$ J(a) ={\pi \over 4}\log\left(2\right) + {\pi \over 4}
\log\left(1 + \sqrt{\, 1 - Ca^{2}\, }\right)$$
can easily be justified looking at the series expansions built around $a=0$
$$I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}   \log (2)-\frac{\pi  }{16}a^2-\frac{9 \pi  }{512}a^4-\frac{25 \pi 
   }{3072}a^6+O\left(a^8\right)$$
$$J(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}   \log (2)-\frac{\pi  C}{16} a^2 -\frac{3\pi 
   C^2}{128} a^4 -\frac{5\pi  C^3}{384} a^6 +O\left(a^8\right)$$ Since $C\sim 0.915966 $, this makes the coefficients quite similar (their ratios are $C$, $\frac{4}{3} C^2$,  $\frac{8 }{5}C^3$).

If you need approximations, you could probably think about $[2n,2n]$ Padé approximants of the ${_4 F_3}$ hypergeometric function (built around $a=0$).

Comment: This is very elegant.The given answer was arrived at by comparing the numerical integration estimates and imposing the well-known results for a = 0 and a =1.Since it is difficult to compute the hypergeometric function or elliptic integrals, a simpler equation was attempted solely by trial and error . The constant that was invoked was later identified as Catalan constant

Comment: @sangara. The approximation is very good close to the end points but is shows a maximum error of $0.0055$ around $a\sim 0.73$. For a quick eveluation, it is very fine. Why not to tabulate the exact values and use interpolation ?

Comment: The complete tabulation for all values are available in various places but my interest consists in providing a simple mathematical expression for the entire partition function containing two additional terms along with this integral. These need to be subjected later on to double differentiation so as to obtain specific heat etc.

Comment: @sangara.Notice that the approximation $J(a)$ is not correct for $a=1$ and still worse for the derivative at this point.

Comment: At a =1,the value arising from the numerical integration is nearly 0.743138 while the approximate formula yields 0.74461.However, the derivative at 'a' =1 is  worse as mentioned by Claude and is a matter of concern since the derivative at 'a' =1 has a physical significance.

Answer (score 0):

I take a different approach to get a simpler approximation formula.

In terms of convenience i use $x$ instead of $\phi$.

Let's use a simple approximation formula:
$$\ln(1+x)\approx \frac{\ln 2}{3}x(4-x)$$

Taking into account this formula, (i will skip routine calculations) $I(a)$ takes an approximate form:
$$I(a)\approx\frac{a^2-2}{12}\pi \ln 2+\frac{4}{3}\ln 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1 - a^{2}\sin^{2}x}\,dx$$

The integral(elliptic) still appears here. To overcome this obstacle we use the next approximation formula:

$$\sqrt{1 - x}\approx 1 - x^2 $$

With this approximation the integral can be computed in closed form and we get finally the following approximation for $I(a)$

$$I(a)\approx(6+a^2-3a^4)\frac{\pi}{12}\ln 2$$

The approximation error within $0<a<1$ is about $0.05$ on average.

Now, there arose a question about the derivative of $I(a)$ i.e. $I'(a)$

From a comment:

"the derivative at 'a' =1 has a physical significance."

But

$$I'(1)=\infty$$

It is difficult to understand where a physical significance is hidden here.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.This solution is more useful pedagogically . The given integral arises in the estimation of the partition function of two-dimensional square lattice models. The physical significance mentioned  is that at a^2=1, the second derivative of the partition function with respect to temperature( i.e specific heat) has a logarithmic singularity as was shown by Onsager (Phys Rev  65(1944)117).This is also related to phase transitions in magnetic systems.